# Name for concise sentence with articles and verbs removed

Tags: sentence-patterns

Suppose I am writing a sign for my front gate to warn people of the dog in the yard. I would write "Warning: Dog in Yard" as opposed to "Warning: There is a dog in the yard". The former removes many words from the sentence but the meaning is still clear.

Is there a name for this kind of concise sentence where the articles, verbs and adverbs are removed? I have found I use this kind of sentence a lot in my day-to-day work where brevity is important.

Comment: I don't have a name but would describe it with the adjective *Terse*.

Comment: Your example is not a sentence precisely because it lacks a verb. It is a fragment or a type of shorthand. I am pretty sure this question has been asked more than once, it's here somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

This style is known as **headlinese** ([see Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headline#Headlinese)); despite the name it is commonly found in a variety of contexts such as road signs. It typically involves (among other things) the omission of articles (*a, an, the*) and forms of *to be,* as in the example you cite.

Comment: I don't think road signs saying "Stop", "Roadworks"  or "No entry" can be described as headlinese.

Comment: I've found a signmaking company which in [its guidelines on writing signs](https://www.mysafetysign.com/how-to-design-an-osha-sign) calls this "headline style" ("write in a headline style", it advises tersely).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In short (pun intended) this would be called a 'truncated' sentence. This is a sentence where a word or words are missing but are generally understood. Truncated sentences can be used to convey haste, urgency, tension, or informality, for example.

Examples:

He is shorter than I (am).

(I) Love it! (I) Just love it!

Got that? (Did you understand that?)

See Cambridge Dictionary: 'truncated' (adjective) made shorter or quicker, especially by removing the end of something

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).